# Flash Player not displaying some characters

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Okay, so I'm setting up a Flash website and everything is working perfectly except for one thing.

The portfolio loads the Titles and Descriptions from an XML file in the following way:

```
<thumbnail filename="/mo*******s/01.JPG" label="Vjagg" 
url="http://www.**********.com/****/… 
description="Vjagg" />
```

(I used the * to hide the original names from here).

Anyway, all the Titles and Descriptions I write there, are displayed correctly in my website, with the exception of V, j and G. At least those are the characters I've noticed to be missing. Anything else, works PERFECT. v, J and g works i.e. Capitalization makes a difference.

thumbnail filename= location of thumbnail (works perfectly)
label= name / title given to art work (V, j and G problem)
url= url for enlarged image (works perfectly)
description= additional details given to art work (V, j and G problem)

The ActionScript2.0 Code regarding that is here:

```
function create_item_list():Void
{
    for( i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        var item = item_list.fm_item.duplicateMovieClip("fm_item"+i, i);
        item._y = i * (item_list.fm_item._height + item_spacing);
        item.item_label.text = item_label[i];
        item.no = i;

        item.item_button.onRelease = function()
        {
            this._parent._parent._parent.change_item(this._parent.no);
        }
    }
    change_item(0); // load the first item detail
}
function change_item(no:Number):Void
{
    title.text = item_label[no];
    description.text = item_description[no];
    this.item_pic.loadMovie(folder + item_filename[no]);
    button.onRelease = function()
    {
        getURL(item_url[no], "_blank");
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Painting work Name: Vjagg
Painting work Description: Vjagg

Result --->
Name: agg
Description: agg
```

Anything else works fine, and those characters if hardcoded in Flash, work well. Only through XML files.

Any ideas please?

I'm using Adobe Flash Professional CS5, however these are simple plain text XML files.
Player: Flash Player 8 (I tried 10 as well - useless)
Script: ActionScript 2.0

I tried editing the XML files both in Notepad and Notepad++, and I also tried saving both in ANSI and UTF-8. Made no difference.

I also re-installed Flash Player both for Firefox/Chrome and for Windows Internet Explorer.

I tried deleting the cache. Didn't help.

I also used it on another computer to make sure. Same problem exactly!

Thankss!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. if the font outline isn't erroneous. There are many fonts the metrics of which is utterly messed up. Try another font and see if it works;
2. if you're dealing with the embedded font. If so, ensure that the characters that are missing are actually embedded.

Over the years, Flash has had countless issues with font embedding and text layout engine in general. I've described one of such matters in [Embedding fonts in Flash CS3](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/embedding-fonts-in-flash-cs3).

Comment: Great. Found the troublesome font! Thanks! :)

Comment: Great you got it. Always a bloody headache if it comes down to something like this after a long debug session!